# Selenium sendKeys(input) function executes before previous function has completed

Tags: c#, selenium

Encountered an issue with a selenium automation script to login into a 'Trello' account.
During execution of code pasted below, the password is entered before second login button is clicked.

My perception is that the occurrence of the id selector for the password input are same in both places.

- 1st place is the [trello login page](https://trello.com/login), after we pass the registered email,  it will show another login button
- 2nd place is when we get redirected to the [atlassian login page](https://id.atlassian.com/login?application=trello&continue=https%3A%2F%2Ftrello.com%2Fauth%2Fatlassian%2Fcallback%3FreturnUrl%3D%252F%26display%3D%26aaOnboarding%3D%26updateEmail%3D%26traceId%3D6284c3b8d64357e7b88522c24cce65af%26migrateGoogle%3D%26ssoVerified%3D&email=testleguser%40gmail.com&errorCode&login_hint=testleguser%40gmail.com&restrict=true)

Code execution steps:

1. get to trello
2. click login
3. enter the login credentials
4. wait and click another login button
5. enter the password
6. login into account and check for board name

In debug mode it does above, while in a regular execution run it passes the  password before clicking the next login button.

I have added the following to the code:

```
IWebElement findGoogleLoginButton = wait.Until((d) => d.FindElement(
            By.Id("google-auth-button")));
```

The intention of the above is to force the script to wait for right input window however I don't find this as a viable solution. Could you please help me understand why this occurs in normal execution mode and not in debug? What is best way to resolve this for normal execution?

```
public void loginToAccount() {
        using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

            //go to main page
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(trelloHomeUrl);

            //find login button and click it
            IWebElement loginButton = driver.FindElement(
                By.CssSelector(".btn.btn-sm.btn-link.text-primary"));
            loginButton.Click();

            //find input field for login and pass data
            IWebElement loginInput = driver.FindElement(
                By.CssSelector("#user"));
            loginInput.SendKeys(login);

            //wait for another login button and click it after passing login
            IWebElement logWithAtlas = driver.FindElement(
                By.CssSelector("#login"));
            logWithAtlas.Click();

            //this was purly added because next step passwordInput pass password before button above is pressed
            IWebElement findGoogleLoginButton = wait.Until((d) => d.FindElement(
                By.Id("google-auth-button")));

            //find input field for password and pass data 
            IWebElement paswordInput = wait.Until((d) => d.FindElement(
                By.Id("password")));
            paswordInput.SendKeys(password);

            //find login button and click it
            IWebElement loginIntoPage = wait.Until((d) => d.FindElement(
                By.XPath("//*[@id='login-submit']")));
            loginIntoPage.Click();

            //get board name and compare to original
            IWebElement webBoardName = wait.Until((d) => d.FindElement(
                By.ClassName("boards-page-board-section-header-name")));

            Assert.Equal(webBoardName.Text, boardName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `ElementToBeClickable` in the definition of `logWithAtlas`?

Comment: Wasn't this be from deprecated selenium.extras? I tried to use it but I could not find it in nuget packages :/ However I thought about creating more specific selector using xpath - because `logWithAtlas` works correctly but it looks like password is passed faster than it should.

Comment: Not sure about c#, but in python it is not deprecated. Did you try putting some `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` before the password is put in the input?

Comment: Did it and it work however as I understood from various sources it's not good practice therefore i added `findGoogleLoginButton`, but still i suspect that issue might be due to selector (as input is named in both forms)